# How to I ensure that all items in an $in clause return a match in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am working with a set of documents like this:

```
{
    name : "BCC 204", 
    //etc
}
```

I have a list of names that I want to map to their DB entries.

For example:

```
var names = [ "BCC 204", "STEW 101", "SMTH 123" ]
```

and I want to make a query like this

```
db.labs.find( { name : { $in: names } } );
```

But the `$in` operator does not ensure that each item in the names array matches a result in the db.

(More info, names are unique)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this in the query. `$in` will check that a document matches at least one entry in the array given, but it's not going to consider the entire result set. This is a concern you'll need to manage in your application. Given a list of inputs, you will need to retrieve your results then check that `given_names - results.map(:name)` is empty.

To put it more simply, queries match documents, which compose a result set - they don't match a result set.

Comment: Currently I am making separate requests for each item which is obviously slow, so that was my other option if I couldn't do it all in the db.

Comment: You can still do the one query to return all documents which match any of those names, but validating that each of the queried items is present in your result set is something you should do in your application.

Comment: The answer and comments are totally right, but since the OP mentioned that names are unique, if a value in the `names` array matches either 0 or 1 documents and never any other number of documents, then you do know that each item matches a result in the db if (and only if) `names.length === db.labs.count({ "name" : { "$in" : names } })`. As soon as one `name` value lives in more than one document, you lose this guarantee, so you'd need to be very careful to maintain uniqueness of names (maybe have a unique index).